# Can we create a document with user having read permission only? C# SP2016

Tags: 2016, visual-web-part, runwithelevatedprivileges

I am working with Visual WebPart in SP2016. I have created Farm Solution. I have a user **TestUserRead**. This user have read permission to the site.

Can I create a document with **TestUserRead** using `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` in my server side SharePoint programming?

If not, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is that standard way to execute a method with full control rights even if the user doesn't have the full control to do that stuff normally.

To use `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` you can do it as below:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.URL))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            // your code to create documents
        }
    }
});
```

Another much cleaner method to impersonate would be to use the System Account's token and then run your method as below:

```
SPSite mysite = new SPSite("https://site-collection-url");
SPUserToken systoken = mysite.SystemAccount.UserToken;
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(mysite.ID, systoken))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        // your code to create documents
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @trimantra, is this code working for you ? if yes, could you please mark it as answer , so it wont show up for us in the unanswered section. Thanks !